# Triggering and looping a CSS3 animation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I am trying to implement a loading animation on an `input` element.  I want the animation to be triggered when the search button on the page has been clicked, and stop when the search has returned (in the callback).

As I'm using AngularJS, currently this is set up as an `$http.get` call and associated `.success` callback, so I already have the perfect places in which to add the triggering and the stopping.

Looking at my [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaQYzo) you should be able to see what I am trying to  do.  The animation should run like this:

- first, the bar slides in from the left until it fully extends the width of the `input`
- then, it slides off in the same direction
- once it's fully disappeared, the animation restarts

In my example I have used `:hover` to trigger the animation, but eventually this should trigger from JavaScript.

How do I start and end the animation cycle in JavaScript, and how do I make it loop indefinitely until stopped?

[Credit]

[http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-sliding-underline](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-sliding-underline/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an animation and then toggle the class:

**HTML**

```
<div class="sliding-u-l-r-l" id="inputElement">
  <input type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Hover over me to demo">
</div>

<input type="button" id="start" value="Start" />
<input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop" />
```

**CSS**

```
.sliding-u-l-r-l {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.sliding-u-l-r-l.animate:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #4ad;
    animation: animation 1.5s infinite;
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
  }  

  50% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%;
  }

  100% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#start").on("click", function() {
  $("#inputElement").addClass("animate");
});

$("#stop").on("click", function() {
  $("#inputElement").removeClass("animate");
});
```

If you wont, you can alternate the animation as well (pretty cool effect) just change:

```
animation: animation 1.5s infinite;
```

to

```
animation: animation 1.5s infinite alternate;
```

**Code pen result**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOQBox

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the example.  I have some reading to do.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want just build a keyframe with animation? Just add infinite to animation iteration count and you are ready...

```
@keyframes slideAnimation {
  0%:{
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
    }
  100%:{
    width: 100%;
    background: #4ad;}
}
input.animate {
  animation: slideAnimation 800ms ease infinite normal 0ms running;
}
```

Then just toggle classes of your input.